# mySQLi check that parent_category matches category_id = 0

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to do this is 1 query, I could easily do it in multiple, but that's not optimal. I have a table something like:

```
    category_id |  parent_category | status
    1           |  0               |  0
    2           |  0               |  1
    3           |  1               |  0
    4           |  2               |  0
```

my query looks like this so far

```
    SELECT
    c.slug
    , c.parent_category
    FROM categories c
    INNER JOIN products p
    ON (p.category_id = c.category_id)
    WHERE
    c.status = '0'
    AND (SELECT count(p.product_id)>0)
    AND p.product
    GROUP BY p.category_id
```

Right now this will show me category_id 1, 3, 4. but 4s parent (2) has a status of 1. I don't want 4 to show, so I'm trying to come up with something that says if parent_categories category_id=0 show if it's 1 then don't.

for the life of me, I cannot work this out.

Comment: I don't think `AND (SELECT count(p.product_id) > 0)` does what you think it does. It's not correlated to the current row, so it's just counting all the products in the product ID table.

Comment: Your query already requires that there be at least one product in the category, because the `INNER JOIN` will not match any rows without a product.

Comment: Your question is confusing. You say you don't want 4 to show because the parent's status is 1. But then you say you want to check if the parent has `category_id = 0`. So which do you want to check, the category ID or the status?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join the table with itself to get information about the parent category.

```
SELECT c.slug, c.parent_category
FROM categories c
JOIN categories parent ON c.parent_category = parent.category_id
JOIN products p ON p.category_id = c.category_id
WHERE c.status = 0 and parent.status = 0
```

Comment: You're seriously the best! I mean it's very obvious when you put it like that, but you still solved my problem thank you!